# No field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier

Tags: java, android, api, http

I am making a simple KeyAuth app on Android and using this API as an example: https://github.com/SprayDown/KeyAuth-JAVA-api
Below are the function I've been trying to work on and the gradle file for the application.

```
HttpResponse<String> response;
try {
    response = response = Unirest.post(url).field("type", "init").field("ver", version)
            .field("name", appname).field("ownerid", ownerid).asString();
} catch (UnirestException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above is the code I've been trying to run and getting the error. And here is my gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mercyz.regvnapk"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.15'
    implementation group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpasyncclient', version: '4.1.4'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.13'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.14'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore-nio', version: '4.4.14'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.5.13'
    implementation 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.15'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20210307'
    implementation group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.9'

    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
}
```

Wonder what's going wrong with this.

Comment: Note that `AllowAllHostnameVerifier` is going to get you banned from the Play Store. The sample code you linked to is for Java SE, not Android.

Comment: Can it run on Android, at least? I saw that example of the API and just copied...

Comment: "Can it run on Android, at least?" -- I have no idea, but your error suggests that perhaps it cannot.